# image map/ area coordinate update on resize

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a main control page with different links on a image now the only problem is I want the image to fit the whole page and re-size (the window) if they shrink it (to a certain degree) and enlarge it.

```
<img src ="image/main.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%; min-width:600px; min-height:400px;" alt="Main" usemap="#MainMap">

<map name="MainMap">
<area id="login" class="login" shape="circle" coords="91,677,92">
<area id="money_management" class="money" shape="circle" coords="598,680,92">
<area id="withdraw_history" shape="circle" coords="596,304,67">
<area id="transaction_history" shape="circle" coords="784,624,67" href="History.html">
<area id="cart" shape="circle" coords="396,698,67,92">
<area id="buy" shape="circle" coords="898,352,92">
<area id="sell" shape="circle" coords="718,438,92">
<area id="new" shape="circle" coords="570,132,92" href="New.html">
</map>
```

I had this before when i made the image static and left it to work on something else, I wanted the coordinates to be updated after they re-size the window I know how to detect re-size in jquery I can't find any syntax example on updating coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a great jQuery PlugIn that does exactly what you wanted:

[Responsive Image Maps jQuery Plugin](http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html)

```
/*    
* rwdImageMaps jQuery plugin v1.4    
*    
* Allows image maps to be used in a responsive design by recalculating 
* the area coordinates to match the actual image size on load and 
* window.resize     
*    
* Copyright (c) 2012 Matt Stow    
* https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps    
* http://mattstow.com    
* Licensed  under the MIT license
*/
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

David Bradshaw wrote a nice little library that solves this problem. It can be used with or without jQuery.

Available here: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/imagemap-resizer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scraping the image map and use divisions with absolute hyperlinks instead and resizing it base on the division. Wanted to avoid that but guess what works, is better then nothing.